# Ежедневные сообщения вк бота в беседу(вк апи ,питон)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Как сделать так, чтобы бот беседы отправлял сообщения ежедневно в определенное время сам? К примеру, есть список ,бот возращает какой то рандомный элемент из списка, допустим, в 18:00 ежедневно. Буду рад, если будет пример с кодом!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, вы можете использовать библиотеку [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/), которая будет запускать вашу задачу в определенное время.